# Why does my feof loop run infinitely, even though the file does end?

Tags: c, loops, file, feof

So I want to count the lines of the file I have as the argument of the function, but I don't know why does this loop run indefinitely.

```
int count_numbers(FILE *filea) {
    int i;
    while (!feof(filea)) {
        i++;
    }
    fclose(filea);
    i--;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: `feof` doesn't take in anything new. If the file descriptor wasn't already marked as being at the end of file, it won't suddenly be EOF in the loop.

Comment: See [Why is `while(!feof(fp))` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

Comment: Why hasn't this been closed as a duplicate in under two minutes? [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 3):

Your function does not count the lines at all and it has multiple problems:

- `i` is not initialized
- [`while (!feof(filea))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?rq=1)
- you do not test if the byte read is a newline
- closing the file should be the caller's responsibility

Here is a modified version:

```
int count_lines(FILE *filea) {
    int c;
    int last = '\n';
    int lines = 0;

    while ((c = getc(filea)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            lines++;
        last = c;
    }
    if (last != '\n') {
        // last line does not have a trailing newline, adjust the count
        lines++;
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: How does this function use `filea`?

Comment: @user1717828: oops! answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the loop can possibly change the file's EOF flag. All that's in the loop is `i++;` which cannot cause the end of the file to be encountered. So the loop will loop an infinite number of times if it loops once.

Comment: Meta-question about your answer: I noticed you started with one-sentence answer and then started updating it to fill out the sentence with more detail.  I also notice you have a really high reputation and probably know a thing about getting reputation on SO.  I wonder: is the idea to get something in with as early a timestamp as possible to dissuade other answerers from starting a response, or is there another reason to iterate from a stub answer like this?

Comment: @user1717828: This question is likely to be closed very quickly. David might have tried and succeeded at posting an answer before this... But I am only guessing.

Comment: @user1717828 I think it's a combination of two things. Part of it is that I always think of something I should have said right after it's too late but I think another is having the painful experience of composing a long, thoughtful answer to a good question only to have the question closed or deleted. Also, a close as a duplicate often doesn't help the OP while an answer that's "mostly" a duplicate does.